# N-th largest component of bwconncomp including the background

Tags: matlab, image-processing

My question has two parts. First one is:

How can I include the background as a component in the `bwconncomp` function, because it's default behavior doesn't include it.

Also, and this is my other question is, how can I select the n-th largest component based on what I get by using `bwconncomp`.

Currently I was thinking about something like this, but that doesn't work :P

```
function out = getComponent(im,n)
CC = bwconncomp(im,4);
%image is an binary image here

numPixels = cellfun(@numel,CC.PixelIdxList);
sortedPixels = sort(numPixels,'descend');
w = sortedPixels(n);
[largest, index] = find(numPixels==w);
im(CC.PixelIdxList{index}) = 0;
out = im;
```

But that doesn't work at all. But im not too sure what the `CC.PixelIdxList{index}` does, is it just changing elements in the array. I also find it kinda vague what exactly `PixelIdxList` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To find the background, you can use 'not' operation on the image
2. **'PixelIdxList'** is not what you need. You need the **'Area'** property.

> function FindBackgroundAndLargestBlob
>       x = imread('peppers.png');
>       I = x(:,:,2);
>       level = graythresh(I);
>       bw = im2bw(I,level);
>       b = bwlabel(bw,8);
>       rp = regionprops(b,'Area','PixelIdxList');
>       areas = [rp.Area];
>       [unused,indexOfMax] = max(areas);
>       disp(indexOfMax);
>   end

Update:
You can do it with bwconncomp as well:

> function FindBackgroundAndLargestBlob
>       x = imread('peppers.png');
>       I = x(:,:,2);
>       level = graythresh(I);
>       bw = im2bw(I,level);
>       c = bwconncomp(bw,4);
>       numOfPixels = cellfun(@numel,c.PixelIdxList);
>       [unused,indexOfMax] = max(numOfPixels);
>       figure;imshow(bw);
>       bw( c.PixelIdxList{indexOfMax} ) = 0;
>       figure;imshow(bw);
>   end

Which will give the following results:
[image: Before]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. First I indeed did it with `bwlabel`, but I read it's uses are all replaced with `bwconncomp` because of the memory usage.

Comment: @TimoWillemsen, I did it using bwconncomp as well - see the update.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, that's indeed what I need. Only I was wondering, you got the maximum element. But how do you get the n-th?

Comment: @TimoWillemsen, Use sort and take the k-th element. Please consider upvoting my answer and accepting it if it was helpful :)

Comment: Yes it is really helpful! I was just checking it out :D And it seems to work. Ofcourse I need to use regionprops `area` property. It does my job. And thanks my code is like 10 times faster now :D